# sql convert/cast varchar(255) to datetime

Tags: sql, datetime, varchar

I am trying to convert varchar(255) to datetime. I tried using convert:

```
Insert into contingentTable 
(startDate)

Select 
convert (datetime,startDate, 120) from tempTable
```

I am getting a

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string.

tempTable field is startdate, its data type is varchar(255), and a example is '05/21/2013 00:00:00.000000'
contingentTable field is startdate, its data type is datetime, and a example is 2013-05-21 00:00:00.000

So basically I need to go from 05/21/2013 00:00:00.000000 to 2013-05-21 00:00:00.000

Any help?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries) - you should **not** store dates as strings - you're just asking for trouble that way. Use the `DATE` or `DATETIME` datatypes!

Answer (score 2):

Well, considering the consistency of the data (i.e. it's extremely well known), you can do this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,
    SUBSTRING('05/21/2013 00:00:00.000000', 1,
        LEN('05/21/2013 00:00:00.000000') - 3),
    120)
```

because the issue is simply the precision. So more specifically, you'd want:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,
    SUBSTRING(startDate, 1, LEN(startDate) - 3),
    120)
```